# How to create many secrets in AWS secrets manager using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

What I want to do is feed a list of key names to a module that will be used to generate many secrets with different random passwords in secrets manager.

I have tried many different things but have failed so far.

This is what I have currently:

```
module "secrets-manager-1" {

  source = "lgallard/secrets-manager/aws"

  for_each = var.list
  secrets = {
    "${each.value}" = {
      description             = each.value
      recovery_window_in_days = 7
      secret_string           = random_password.special_password.result
    }
  }

  tags = var.standard_tags
}

resource "random_password" "special_password" {
  count = 2
  length = 16
  special = true
}

variable "list" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = [
    "secret_key_1",
    "secret_key_2"

  ]
}
```

The Error:

```
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on ..\..\modules\jitsi\jitsi_secrets.tf line 54, in module "secrets-manager-1":
│   54:   for_each = var.list
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.list is list of string with 2 elements
│
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type list of string.
╵
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
```

Comment: You have described the desired behavior, but not the current behavior. I'm not going to run this just to see what it does so I understand your issue. Please include any actual errors or undesired behavior in the question itself.

Comment: Hi Mark, Apologies here is the error:

│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on ..\..\modules\jitsi\jitsi_secrets.tf line 54, in module "secrets-manager-1":
│   54:   for_each = var.list
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.list is list of string with 2 elements
│
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type list of string.
╵
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...

Comment: Please add the error to the question as @MarkB requested instead of in a comment.

Comment: Click the `edit` button under your question. Add the error to the actual question itself, formatted so we can read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are providing is not even valid Terraform code. What I believe you would want to achieve the following:

```
// Create N random password. In this case N = 2
resource "random_password" "special_password" {
  count   = 2
  length  = 16
  special = true
}

// Import a third party module
module "secrets-manager-1" {

  source = "lgallard/secrets-manager/aws"

  // Loop through the random_passowrd resouces and create the secrets
  secrets = {
      for index, pwd in random_password.special_password.*.result : "${element(var.list, index)}" => {
          secret_string: "${pwd}",
          recovery_window_in_days = 7
      }
  }
}
```

You may want to check out the [splat expressions](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) for being able to iterate over multiple resources. This is used for the `for` expression in the `secrets-manager-1` module.

Comment: You sir are a legend! I did notice my mistake after commenting. You may want to add   " count   = length(var.list) " to the random_password so when you update the list you don't need to up the number. (That is what I did in my now working code :)